# Remove duplicates words in same line?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, tr, uniq

I want to Remove duplicates words in same line and save the sentence Without changing the location of non-repeating words

my text.txt

```
Linux systems with unix systems 
shell script is the best script
```

The output needed

```
Linux systems with unix 
shell script is the best
```

I used this script :

```
    tr ' ' '\n' <my_text.txt |  xargs -n1 | sort -u | xargs
```

But the output is sane the input data :

```
linux systems with unix 
shell script is the best
```

Any advice to find the perfect solution for this example ?
**note : i dont use `awk`**

Comment: I distinctly remember a very similar question from six months or a year ago, though I can't find it now. I strongly suspect that this is homework. If so, please see [this guidance.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)